# Mathematica: Simplify with user-defined function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Input:

```
f[x_] := Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]
f'[x]
```

Output:

```
x / Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]
```

**How do I get Mathematica to replace the denominator by `f[x]` itself?** (Note: this is a simple example of a more complicated differentiation problem, in which the function itself is complicated but shows up a lot in the derivative.)

That is, **desired Output** is:

```
x / f[x]
```

I tried

```
Simplify[f'[x], TransformationFunctions -> {f}]
```

but to no avail. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you do define `f`, it will not be possible to have it in the output as it would immediately auto-evaluate.  If you type `x / f[x]
` and press shift-enter, it'll also give you `x / Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]
`

Answer (score 1):

I think it's very hard to do this in general; in your specific example one can use a rule such as

```
rules = {z_^2 + y^2 -> Hold[f[z]^2]};
```

and then

```
f'[x] /. rules

(* x/Sqrt[Hold[f[x]^2]] *)

f''[x] /. rules

(* -(x^2/Hold[f[x]^2]^(3/2)) + 1/Sqrt[Hold[f[x]^2]] *)
```

Working with the square root is more difficult and I think one rule is not enough, the basic reason being :

```
Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] // FullForm
1/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] // FullForm
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it like this:

```
Clear[f,g]
g[expr_]:=expr/.(x_^2+y_^2):> (f[x])^2
Simplify[D[Sqrt[x^2+y^2],x],TransformationFunctions->{Automatic,g},Assumptions->f[x]>0]
```

it will give `x/f[x]` as a result.